# Scroll position of webcontrol in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, web-control

I wonder how can I save the scroll position of large html in webcontrol in windows phone lets say a bookmarking ?

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

One technique I have used:

```
WebBrowser.ScriptInvoke( "exec", "window.external.notify(
[window.outerWidth 
, window.outerHeight
, window.pageXOffset
, window.pageYOffset
, document.body.style.zoom
].join('|')");
```

and catch the resulting string in `WebBrowser.ScriptNotify` event handler.

This runs a javascript on any page the user has currently loaded, you don't need to modify the page itself.  You must wait till the `WebBrowser.LoadCompleted` event to make sure the page is stable.

If you know user didn't zoom the web page, you wouldn't need the zoom, outerWidth and outerHeight.

Comment: Thank you but I found this method easier ,Just add these procedures to every Html page:<script>
function getVerticalScrollPosition() {
    return document.body.scrollTop.toString();
}
function setVerticalScrollPosition(position) {
    document.body.scrollTop = position;
}
</script> And execute it using InvokeScript

Comment: That sounds fine if you have control of the web pages the user loads.